# In Karate framework, how do you unset proxy

Tags: karate

Let's say in my karate script, I have

- configure proxy = 'http://proxy.server-biglib.com:80'

and let's say for some of my tests which do no need proxym how I can unconfigure that
if I put

- configure proxy = ''
  will throw an error

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this conditionally:

```
* if (condition) karate.configure('proxy', 'http://my.proxy.host:8080')
```